# USB issue when building a Unity project into an android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, usb-drive, building

I created an Augmented reality application using Unity. The app works perfectly when testing on my windows platform. However, after finishing it I am trying to build and run it on an android device I keep getting the following message:

[PS. debugging mode is enabled, the device is also accepted by the computer and it appears for me when I am fetching for connected devices. (I had also try several devices and change the USB cable but the problem remains)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmS47.jpg)

Does anyone know what should I do to build successfully the app?

Comment: UnityException: Make sure USB debugging has been enabled and that the device has authorized this computer. Check your device, in most cases, there should be a small icon in the status bar telling you if the USB connection is up. If you are sure that the device is attached then it might be USB driver issue, for details please check 'Android environment setup' section in Unity manual.

Comment: Try using android studio to build on device. If you simply build instead of build and run, then open the exported project using android studios it should give you a lot more information than using Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your device has the **USB Debugging** option enabled in the **Developer Options**

If your device hasn't the developer options enabled, follow these steps:

1- Go to device settings, in your device.

2- In the menu **About phone** you have to find the **Build number**

3- Click repeatedly on the **Build Number** until Developer Options are enabled.